# How to connect vertices in a mesh efficiently?

Tags: mesh, vertices

[image: image 1]
Suppose If I have a concentric rings as in image 1, then how to connect the vertices among the rings efficiently, so that I can achieve what is in image 2

[image]

Comment: If they have the same amount of vertices try selecting all rings and *Bridge Edge Loops*

Comment: I edited your post, because in Blender, the designation *merging* is used for a different operation than you are asking for. Merging is the act of taking two or more vertices, and combining them into a single vertex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a surface from edge rings using the Looptools Loft tool or use Blender's default operator *Bridge Edge Loops*.

**LoopTools addon**

[image]

If you don't have the Looptools enabled, enable them through the user preferences:
[image]

To use the Loft tool, select your loops in the order you want to connect them (the order is important).

Then either go to the Tools panel on the left --> Looptools --> Loft (as seen in the gif above).

Or: open the specials menu using <kbd>W</kbd> --> Looptools --> Loft.

**Bridge Edge Loops**

Select edge loops, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops* (or find it in menu of 3D View header: *Mesh* > *Edges* > *Bridge Edge Loops*).

[image: bridge edge loops]

Comment: Blender's default 'Bridge Edge Loops' does the same as 'Loft'.

Comment: Right, thanks @RayMairlot and thanks for the edit, Mr Zak