# Having trouble joining two edges

Tags: modeling, edges

[image: First]
[image: Second]

I'm still a beginner and decided to model a lightsaber from a CG GEEK tutorial linked [here](https://youtu.be/YbsYDOiph7U).

I've been having some trouble joining two faces after running into trouble from double vertices in my mesh. I noticed it when I applied a subdivision surface and I've been having trouble solving it. The biggest detail that I've noticed is that the new vertices that were created when I tried to fill in the gap with the fill tool, aren't recognized as a face by Blender. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92725/bridge-extrude-join-vertices-in-a-ring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the fill tool. Delete that big and ugly n-gon shown in the pictures, then select the edge loops you want to join (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>), and press the space bar and type **Bridge Edge loops**

[image]

Read: [How to connect vertices in a mesh efficiently?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48155/how-to-connect-vertices-in-a-mesh-efficiently/48156#48156).

Then, if you are using a subsurf modifier you need to select the edges you want to make sharp and crease them. Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and set the edge crease to a valud of 1.0

read: [Keep sharp edges when using subdivision surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface/6426#6426)

[image]