# How to fill a loop with faces?

Tags: mesh, topology

I have this mesh that I cut the top half off. Now I want to like fill it all around with faces and wonder what tool I could use for that?[image]

Comment: have you tried bridge edge tool?

Comment: I dont know what that is?

Comment: select the two parts that you want to join, press right click to display the context menu > Bridge Edge Loops

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48155/how-to-connect-vertices-in-a-mesh-efficiently and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46342/is-there-a-way-to-fill-the-area-between-two-circles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want more control, select 2 facing nodes and press F till you have filled all the couples with faces.

Check this video: I just pressed F many times:

[image]

Comment: Is that F2 what you're using? Because that crashes with a python error here after I make the bridge and then hit F. Attribute Error: Vector substraction (vector- noneType) invalid type for this operation. https://imgur.com/yuWyZoY

Comment: I've got F2, don't know if this particular feature is a core one or comes from F2 add on.

Comment: Well from the error it seems to be a problem in F2 since it reports the error in the F2 script.

Comment: I confirm that what you see in the video works even without F2 addon (so you can try to disable it forever or disable and re-enable to check if it fixes something)